# Text overflow in quotes

Tags: bug, design

Long words in quotes will overflow. See the first revision of this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2370790/1

I think it would be better if `overflow: scroll` was set, similarly to code blocks.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114743/172936) ;)

Comment: We can use `<pre>` tag for that.

Comment: The `<pre>` will apply a monospaced font, so it's not the same thing.

Comment: Look at [the reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148561/187824)

Comment: Related: some notes on `word-break: break-all` and tricks used in comments, in [Occasionally, the Unicode character sequence U+200C U+200B (ZWNJ ZWSP) is inserted into comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert/171065#171065).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<pre>` or `<blockquote>` use the Markdown method `>` and it comes out correct:

> ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()': ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x5b6): undefined reference to`Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)' ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()': ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x666): undefined reference to`Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)' ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()': ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x6f6): undefined reference to`Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)' ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::initOgreSystem()': ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x1cfb): undefined reference to`Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::allocBytes(unsigned int, char const*, int, char const*)' ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x1dde): undefined reference to `Ogre::Root::initialise(bool, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)' ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x2278): undefined reference to`Ogre::Root::createRenderWindow(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, std::map, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > > const*)' ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x2c31): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)' ogrewidget.o: In function`std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)': ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS2_[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)]+0x40): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::allocBytes(unsigned int, char const*, int, char const*)' ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS2_[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)]+0x10d): undefined reference to`Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)' ogrewidget.o: In function `std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >*)': ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS2_E[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >*)]+0x47): undefined reference to`Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)' collect2: ld returned 1

But if it is code (which it *might* be) just put 4 spaces before it (or highlight it and press `CTRL` + `K`):

```
ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x5b6): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x666): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::~OgreWidget()':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x6f6): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `OgreWidget::initOgreSystem()':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x1cfb): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::allocBytes(unsigned int, char const*, int, char const*)'
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x1dde): undefined reference to `Ogre::Root::initialise(bool, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x2278): undefined reference to `Ogre::Root::createRenderWindow(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, std::map, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > > const*)'
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text+0x2c31): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS2_[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)]+0x40): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::allocBytes(unsigned int, char const*, int, char const*)'
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS2_[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)]+0x10d): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
ogrewidget.o: In function `std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >*)':
ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS2_E[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >, std::less, std::allocator > >, Ogre::STLAllocator, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > >*)]+0x47): undefined reference to `Ogre::NedPoolingImpl::deallocBytes(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1
```

Comment: That's a workaround, but shouldn't blockquote do the same as `>`?

Comment: @fish **No**. Why should it? It is not a workaround.... you shouldn't be using `<blockquote>`, you should be using markdown on the SE sites.

Comment: Don't shout. It should, because otherwise the displayed text might look glitched, as seen in the example. I can't believe I have to defend this. Do you think that text that is displayed on top of other visual elements of the site, completely out of the layout is fine? Using markdown vs. HTML for formatting is a different question. Why allow using HTML tags in the first place? My impression is that such formatting tags are allowed for easier adoption of the site. As long as they are allowed, shouldn't they work correctly?

Comment: @fish See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/148561#148561). I also agree with you; if it's allowed then it *should* work. It'd be preferable to use Markdown though.