# ZWNJ ZWSP insertion breaks link in comments

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

For example:

```
[longlink](http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)-[link](http://example.com/)
```

There is 80 characters until before `(http://example.com/)`.

This comment should be shown like:

> [longlink](http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)-[link](http://example.com/)

but actually:

> [longlink](http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)-[link]‌​(http://example.com/)

Second link is broken by magic characters inserted between `]` and `(`.

<sub>See also: [Occasionally, the Unicode character sequence U+200C U+200B (ZWNJ ZWSP) is inserted into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970/286934)</sub>

Comment: Example: [longlink](http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)-[link](http://example.com/)

Comment: [longlink](http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa), [link](http://example.com/)

Comment: Use `, ` instead of `-`