# Stop inserting invisible characters into comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments

Currently, the SE system inserts invisible characters ([U+200C](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=200C) and [U+200B](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=200B)) into text in comments if there's a "word" longer than 60 characters long, to force a break to preserve the layout. [This is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970); but:

1. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348600/invisible-unicode-characters-inside-code-comments) for the trouble it causes in regard to code in comments, and
2. It doesn't work, because it works by character count, not width:

```css
/* This is the EXISTING wrapper div that gives the comments
   section its width
*/
div.comments {
  width: 660px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;  /* Added for clarity */
}
div.comments table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
This is how wide the comments should be:
<div class="comments">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="comment-162534" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment162534_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
This is how wide they are if you use `W` 60 times and it inserts the invisible characters after 60 chars:
<div class="comments">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="comment-162534" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW‌​WWWWWWWWWW</span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment162534_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

*(Nice catch, [Niet the Dark Absol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295425/stop-inserting-invisible-characters-into-comments?noredirect=1#comment958463_295425))*

I suggest that rather than inserting bug-producing hidden characters, we apply a class to the element containing the over-long word (the `code` element if it's a code run, or a `span` we add for non-code over-long words), with this styling:

```
.too-long {
    word-break: break-all;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 620px;
}
```

…where the 620px is derived from the existing rule applying `width: 660px` on the `div.comments` wrapper div. So if that rule changes, we change this one as well.

On browsers other than Firefox, it could just have the `word-break: break-all`, but sadly Firefox doesn't handle that unless the element has a width fairly directly applied to it. :-(

Doing that, instead of:

```css
/* This is the EXISTING wrapper div that gives the comments
   section its width
*/

div.comments {
  width: 660px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Added for clarity */
}

div.comments table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="comment-123456" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: <code>012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789‌​01234567890123456789</code></span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment123456_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="comment-654321" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffff‌​gggggggggghhhhhhhhhh</span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment654321_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

We'd have:

```css
/* This is the EXISTING wrapper div that gives the comments
   section its width
*/
div.comments {
  width: 660px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;  /* Added for clarity */
}
div.comments table {
  width: 100%;
}

/* The new class, added where necessary */
.too-long {
  word-break: break-all;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 620px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="comment-123456" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: <code class="too-long">01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789</code></span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment123456_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="comment-654321" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: <span class="too-long">aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhh</span></span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment654321_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="comment-162534" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: <span class="too-long">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</span></span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment162534_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

…which in addition to not inserting invisible characters, works correctly with a lot of wide characters like `W`.

If we wanted to special-case Firefox, it could be like this for other browsers:

```css
/* This is the EXISTING wrapper div that gives the comments
   section its width
*/
div.comments {
  width: 660px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;  /* Added for clarity */
}
div.comments table {
  width: 100%;
}

/* The new class, added where necessary */
.too-long {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<strong>Doesn't work on Firefox</strong>
<div class="comments">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="comment-123456" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: <code class="too-long">01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789</code></span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment123456_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="comment-654321" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: <span class="too-long">aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffgggggggggghhhhhhhhhh</span></span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment654321_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="comment-162534" class="comment ">
        <td class="comment-actions">
          <table><tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class=" comment-score"><span title="number of 'useful comment' votes received" class="cool">1</span></td>
              <td><a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this comment adds something useful to the post">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><a class="comment-flag" title="Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention">&nbsp;</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td class="comment-text">
          <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">Sed ut perspiciatis: <span class="too-long">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</span></span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/1234567/joe-bloggs" title="1,234 reputation" class="comment-user">Joe Bloggs</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment162534_987654"><span title="2017-05-01 08:25:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">2 hours ago</span></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Another option is to use `word-wrap: break-word` instead, but that always needs the `display: inline-block` and explicit width, even on Chrome, whereas with `word-break: break-all` we don't need those except on Firefox.

Comment: should code ever be in comments? I mean, how would you even format anything hut a single line ?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Rarely, it can be appropriate, usually in the context of suggesting an improvement to an answer that may go far enough that it would violate the original author's intent if you just made the change.

Comment: I sometimes use code in comments, and find it very useful.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: "should code ever be in comments?" – Comments are often used to ask clarifying questions to the OP of a question. Considering that (at least on [so]) a significant amount of questions are about code, it seems reasonable to assume that at least some clarifications also concern code. "I mean, how would you even format anything hut a single line?" – Depending on the language, a single line can be enough. For example, in Ruby, linebreaks are never required; any Ruby program, no matter how complex, can be written in a single line.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You can write most programming languages in a single line. But just because it’s valid, that doesn’t mean that it’s a good idea or that putting code inside comments is a good idea.

Comment: Even if there was no CSS solution, it would be better to reject the comment, or introduce a space instead of invisible crap, or do almost anything other than silently and invisibly sabotage people's code.

Comment: Even worse than the constant "by-design" claim, is the fact that it doesn't even solve the problem it was designed to solve. See: WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW - a simple `word-wrap:break-word` will resolve this better than `word-break:break-all`, because the latter will break words whenever it can, whereas the former will only break them if necessary.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: ***Excellent*** point, added above.

Comment: I wasn't convinced, until [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAopx.png), which is not un-amusing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I still think `word-wrap:break-word` would be a more appropriate choice, as demonstrated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o97v0b30/)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Added a note for it at the bottom, but sadly it requires the `display: inline-block` and explicit width, even on Chrome, whereas we can avoid those on browsers other than Firefox with `word-break: break-all`. (Unless you can find a way, of course! :-) )

Comment: I don't think the `inline-block` part is required, just the width. The issue on SE is that it uses a table, which will naturally grow in width to accommodate its contents. Adding `table-layout:fixed` to the table will fix this just fine.

Comment: @JasonC I thought it was just me for a second there!

Comment: I've been noticing this on code golf for a while now where full solutions with improvements are commonly posted as comments so that you can copy and paste them in and when trying to compile/run it getting all sorts of errors...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Since the container is a `span` or `code`, yes, you need the `inline-block`; width is meaningless for `inline` elements. Please don't hesitate to propose a better solution, I'm sure there is one! But be sure to use the actual markup and styles, since the details matter. :-) (`table-layout: fixed` with a zero-height header row to set the dimensions may well be a good direction...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder On the current page, I have added `.comments>table{table-layout:fixed} .comment-body{word-wrap:break-word}` - just these two rules fixes all the layout issues caused by my W-spam earlier. Because this should apply to entire comments, not just code within them.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Not for me. If I do that, the comments controls (flags and vote arrows) get messed up. Again, I'm sure there's something there, but it would want fuller demonstration.

Comment: Turns out the invisible Unicode crap happens in chat, too, so let's extend this request to getting rid of the invisible crap in chat. I haven't tested the behavior in questions or answers yet, but it's possible those are affected too (for backtick formatting - unlikely for code blocks).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder For some reason, the comment action "column" is defined as being 15px wide, but the score and icons are clearly bigger than that. So that's why `table-layout:fixed` breaks those... I suppose they will simply need a bigger space defined, one that actually fits the content.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: In any case, I think we've done our part demonstrating that a CSS solution is feasible and desireable.

Comment: For what it's worth, something on this page is causing comments to bleed into the right margin, where the Hot Network Questions etc are overlapped.  Screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhE9R.png

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, that's one of the points of this FR, heh.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The W-spam is still breaking pages in Firefox 54 and IE 11. Also, looks like the repeating-question-mark problem hasn't been fixed in IE yet... still feels like we're living in 2004.

Comment: I realize this is a feature request and the dupe is a bug, but the bug fix implicitly answers the FR, so I'm linking the two together.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Technically, at the time this was posted, the bug report had been marked as "by design", so this was a feature request to change the design. But yeah; since a dev opted to change the tag there rather than update it here, this can be marked as a dupe.

Comment: It's the state of the other question today that matters, not what it was originally.  (I don't think we need to dig into edit history before deciding whether two questions are dupes.)

Answer (score 10):

I really do think that this should be applied. I don't see any disadvantage whatsoever to use something else such as word-warp to solve the problem.

Plus, once this fixed, we will no longer have questions asking why code copied from comments doesn't work.

> But people shouldn't put code into comments, they should post it as an answer.

Although that may be true, why not let code in comments be uncorrupted?

> But that would mean work for developers!

Isn't that what meta is for, <s>bugging</s> requesting things from developers?

Answer (score 6):

This should be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now, according to [balpha ♦'s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307435/388442):

> As of about a month ago, these characters are no longer inserted, since comments are no longer laid out with a `<table>` (and the table layout algorithm was what prevented fixing overflow in any other way).

Comment: Sure looks like it. (I think this should be a *comment*, not an *answer*.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, this type of answer is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog - Citation?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've posted several such answers myself and they've always been up voted rather than deleted as NAAs.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog - So you're working from anecdotal evidence, not a citation. Okay, you have much more experience on MSE than I do.