# Can we stop breaking lines by inserting invisible stuff every 80 characters in chat messages?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, chat

So I raised a sock and ran a testing bot on it. [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43369764#43369764)'s the start of the testing series.

After some testing, I found out that SE is inserting invisible characters `\u200c\u200b` every 80 continuous characters (continuous = not separated by space/tab/newline) in the Markdown source. This has confused quite some bots already and generated some work for bot developers to fix their parsing of messages.

Furthermore, the line breaking implementation is wrong........

[image]

You see, on my phone it's line-broken wrongly, and my bot [showed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43370351#43370351) me what the "rendered" text is:

```
@iBug
'123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
90\u200c\u200b1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567
89012345678901\u200c\u200b2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
78901234567890123456789012\u200c\u200b3456789012345678901234567890'
```

[The source code](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43369887#43369887) I used in my bot is rather simple:

```python
@command(str, whole_msg=True)
def whatis(msg, body):
    return '`' + repr(body) + '`'
```

Can we stop creating line breaks this way? This would better be implemented by CSS.

---

This has caused some trouble for once more: [This message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46536797#46536797) was gracefully broken:

[image]

Comment: @ShadowWizard The same applies to code blocks in comments, so...

Comment: [Not anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert). It was fixed a while ago.

Comment: This is so counterproductive...

Comment: @BhargavRao It's said that Smokey used to do so, but it was later removed for bringing an extra layer of latency.

Comment: Aha, that clarifies my previous message. So it's the new chat layer which screwed up.  :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is fixed. My last commit to the Stack Overflow codebase before I temporarily left two months ago was to change the CSS so it prevents the unwanted overflow, eliminating the need for these characters.