# Preventing word-breaking in flowed paragraphs

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

In questions and answers, I would sometimes like to keep a whole string together, to avoid what's happening to the string `[![:print:]]` here:

> [image: bad hyphenation example]

Is there a trick to avoid breaking a short string?

---

In an earlier revision of this question, I mentioned non-breaking spaces. 
This seemed to derail people's attention (hence the comments below).  This question is about preventing word-breaking, not about how to do non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Side note - if you don’t feel like pressing `Alt` + `Space` then typing `&nbsp;` works as well.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Not within backticks for an in-line code string (or triple backticks for a block). It _does_ work if you use it within a `<code>...</code>` HTML tag, which I never use as I write _lots_ of small code snippets. Every once in a while, that might be useful though.

Comment: I see your point. I’m afraid your best option is to use block formatting rather than inline. Though this should only pertain to exact syntax situations where the incorrect reading of inline hyphenation could lead to undesired behavior.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Hm? Your comment was about non-breaking spaces, not about hyphenation, right? In-line code marked up with `<code>` is still hyphenated at awkward positions. My question is about how to prevent hyphenation of in-line text/code.  If there was something that could be done with HTML attributes in the `<code>` tag, for example, that would be nice.

Comment: As for _Not within backticks for an in-line code string_ in the comment above: please don't add non-breaking spaces in code. It will confuse people a lot when copy/pasting that code.

Comment: @Arjan How would I then best show a string with some trailing spaces in a paragraph, as I did in this question? Note that this is almost never in code that anyone would copy. This is for text _talking about_ code.

Comment: The non-breaking space thing that I mentioned in passing seems to derail people's attention. This question is not about how to do non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Use block formatting - either indent the code with four spaces, use triple ticks or go the html route with `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I don't think that would be appropriate for the example that I show in the question where I talk about a filename globbing pattern. Using a pre+code block for each `[![:print:]]` (or even one of them) would make the text confusing and unreadable.

Comment: I agree with you, it’s better to keep those inline. But for situations in which spacing is part of the syntax (i.e. makefiles, sh builtins, ...) it’s better to block format that code. Basically inline code is going to be broken up or awkwardly placed on a new line if it cannot fit, you can try adding `<br>`s to make it work but it’s going to look weird on other people’s displays.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I'm well aware how code block formatting works. This is not an issue. This is about span elements, i.e. strings in text in flowed paragraphs (see example in question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To prevent the word-break

> In questions and answers, I would sometimes like to keep it together, to avoid this to the string `[![:print:]]` happening

Use a `&#8205;` between all characters, which is a [Zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner)

> In questions and answers, I would sometimes like to keep it together, to avoid this to the string `‍[‍!‍[‍:‍print‍:‍]‍]‍` happening

Above in Markdown:

```
> In questions and answers, I would sometimes like to keep it together
> , to avoid this to the string 
> <code>&#8205;[&#8205;!&#8205;[&#8205;:&#8205;print&#8205;:&#8205;]&#8205;]&#8205;</code> happening
```

Far from convenient to create (or use later on (copy/paste)) but that was not stated as a requirement.

Comment: Urgh. Yeah, _far from convenient_, but possibly still useful under under some limited circumstances.

Comment: Or use it as code on a separate linr, that also doesn't break. As per your markdown piece.

Comment: I feel adding zero-width joiners will confuse people who copy the code. It might also affect search. (And aside, this is optimizing for _some_ views, typically the regular desktop browser, but not for others such as the mobile view or any usage of the data dumps, which might flow the text differently.) Related, the auto-inserted magic in comments, that confused people too: [Occasionally, the Unicode character sequence U+200C U+200B (ZWNJ ZWSP) is inserted into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert).

Comment: If I copy and paste your example with the zero-width joiner in it, that invisible character can stay as part of the pasted text, possibly resulting in some strange, bizarre, or hard to understand errors, depending on how that character is handled.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm and we all love those errors, right?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this qualifies as an answer, but I think you should not care too much about this, because you *can't completely prevent* these kind of things happening. Perfecting your posts is commendable, but in this case your energy might be better spent elsewhere, e.g. finding and writing an answer to another question.

For a real-life example, *this very morning*, I was Googling for how to check the log of `launchctl`. The first [search result](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=launchctl+log&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) is a [Server Fault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/183591/283889) and it's short enough that I don't need to navigate:

[image]

So I copy

```
sudo launchctl log level debug
```

and execute it, and then I copy

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

and execute it. Or so I thought; since Google strips the formatting, that actually ended up being

```
tail -f /var/log/ system.log
```

thanks to the line break. The author of that question wisely chose a code block for their commands, but even that didn't help.

Comment: Above at least the whitespace was visible after pasting. Zero-width fillers, like suggested elsewhere, would add far more confusion.